# Loading a Linear Regression Model back up for Prediction in Rust-linfa

Tags: json, machine-learning, rust, rust-cargo, serde

I have been looking into linfa for Machine Learning in Rust, specifically the Linear Regression model. I want to be able to save and load my trained Linear Regressiom model however I'm unable to find a way to do this.

### **Approach 1:**

So far my approach has been to obtain the main parameters that are involved in training that I can obtain from linfa's implementation of Linear Regression, and store them in a struct that I can store as a JSON file (done through serde_json). After this however I can't figure out how to load it back up for training.

Details of the above are given as follows:

Struct to store trained parameters:

```
struct ModelJson {
    coefficients: Vec<f64>,
    intercept: f64,
}
```

The storing procedure:

```
let model = lin_reg.fit(&dataset)?;
let model_json = ModelJson {
    coefficients: model.params().to_vec(),
    intercept: model.intercept(),
};
```

How the stored data looks:

```
{"coefficients":[-0.00017907873576254802,-0.00100659702068151,-0.0008275037845519519,0.0004613216043979551,0.0010300634934599436],"intercept":50.525680622870084}
```

### **Approach 2:**

With respect to serializing and deserializing the whole model I found the following information stating that there is support for the same in linfa.
[Loading and Saving Models](https://github.com/rust-ml/linfa/issues/67)

This leads us to my second approach wherein I used the serde feature of linfa-linear (containing the LinearRegression model), by including the following in my Cargo.toml first:

`linfa-linear = {version="0.7.0", features=["serde"]}`

This feature implements the following for LinearRegression as per my understanding of the implementation:
[Serde Serialize and Deserialize Implementations - derive](https://serde.rs/derive.html)

Aforementioned Implementation:

```
#[cfg_attr(
    feature = "serde",
    derive(Serialize, Deserialize),
    serde(crate = "serde_crate")
)]
/// A fitted linear regression model which can be used for making predictions.
pub struct FittedLinearRegression<F> {
    intercept: F,
    params: Array1<F>,
}
```

Found in: [linfa-linear derive implementation](https://github.com/rust-ml/linfa/blob/4e40ce6375249bb823bc71de067477b472ae4c01/algorithms/linfa-linear/src/ols.rs#L63)

Which I implemented as follows:

```
let model = lin_reg.fit(&dataset)?;
let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&model).unwrap();
```

This method however gave the following error:

```
the trait bound `FittedLinearRegression<f64>: serde::ser::Serialize` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `serde::ser::Serialize`:
  bool
  char
  isize
  i8
  i16
  i32
  i64
  i128
and 133 othersrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
main.rs(82, 22): required by a bound introduced by this call
```

Is there another way to do this or is there some way I could make one of these approaches work?

Answer (score 0):

in approach 1, you have manually stored the model parameters in a JSON file and then trying to load them back. it might not be able to capture all the necessary information in more complex models. in approach 2, `FittedLinearRegression<f64>`  This is likely due to the fact that f64 doesn't implement the Serialize trait by default in serde. By using `serde_with::serde_as`, you can provide a custom serialization implementation for `FittedLinearRegression<f64>`.

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde_with::serde_as;

#[cfg_attr(feature = "serde", serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct FittedLinearRegression<F> {
    intercept: F,
    params: Array1<F>,
}

let model = lin_reg.fit(&dataset)?;
let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&model).unwrap();
let deserialized: FittedLinearRegression<f64> = serde_json::from_str(&serialized).unwrap();
```

Comment: I tried this approach however with this I get the following error:
`the trait bound ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<F>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>: _::_serde::Deserialize<'_> is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>:
  bool
  char
  isize
  i8
  i16
  i32
  i64
  i128
and 133 othersrustcClick
`

I think that's because params having type Array1 isn't getting serialized. Is there something I've missed with this?